# Sort an array by a list of it's fields

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
Objects = [
{ "id": 1, "name": Joseph, function: "preacher"},
{ "id": 2, "name": Ann, function: "singer"},
{ "id": 3, "name": Miles, function: "preacher"},
{ "id": 4, "name": Jack, function: "singer"},
{ "id": 5, "name": Igor, function: "secretary"}
];
```

And also an array of properties:

```
sort = ['function', 'name'];
```

I have to sort the **Objects** array, using a combination of properties(sort array).
So I did it like this:

```
const intlCollator = new Intl.Collator('pt-BR', { usage: 'sort' });

  Objects.sort(
    (x, y) =>
      (intlCollator.compare(x[sort[0]], y[sort[0]])) ||
      (intlCollator.compare(x[sort[1]], y[sort[1]])) ||
      (intlCollator.compare(x[sort[2]], y[sort[2]]))
    );
```

How would I make the sorting dynamic?
I mean, iterate using variable sort combinations.
For example:

```
sort = ['function', 'name'];
```

Or:

```
sort = ['name'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the keys until a comparing returns a not falsy value.

```js
const
    objects = [{ id: 1, name: "Joseph", function: "preacher" }, { id: 2, name: "Ann", function: "singer" }, { id: 3, name: "Miles", function: "preacher" }, { id: 4, name: "Jack", function: "singer" }, { id: 5, name: "Igor", function: "secretary" }],
    intlCollator = new Intl.Collator('pt-BR', { usage: 'sort' }),
    sort = ['function', 'name'];


objects.sort((a, b) => {
    let r;
    sort.some(k => r = intlCollator.compare(a[k], b[k]));
    return r;
});
    
console.log(objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ES10 [sort is stable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sort_stability). That means you can first sort using the first key, then sort the second and so on.

```js
const Objects = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "Joseph", function: "preacher"},
{ "id": 2, "name": "Ann", function: "singer"},
{ "id": 3, "name": "Miles", function: "preacher"},
{ "id": 4, "name": "Jack", function: "singer"},
{ "id": 5, "name": "Igor", function: "secretary"}
];

const sort = ['name', 'function'];

const intlCollator = new Intl.Collator('pt-BR', { usage: 'sort' });
sort.forEach(s => {
  Objects.sort((l, r) => intlCollator.compare(l[s], r[s]));
});

console.log(Objects);
```